# No simultaneous hover effect on image and selected item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kinda stuck right now in making the website of the company I'm working for. I'm making a timeline for the company activities. Here's my problem: I can't seem to trigger the hover effect on both the image and the text unless I hover only on the image itself.

Here's where I am right now with my HTML:

```
<body><center>
<div class="container" style="overflow:auto; padding: 1em;">
<div class="timeline">
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year">2014<span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-item">
<div class="year"><span class="marker"><span class="dot"></span></span></div>
<div class="info"><img src="sourceOfPicture.png" /><br/>
ACTIVITY INFORMATION HERE</div>
</div>
</div>
</div></center>
```

Here's my css:

```
    <style>
div {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.timeline {
    width: 400px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item {
    width: 100%;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .info, .timeline .timeline-item .year {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.timeline .timeline-item.close .info, .timeline .timeline-item.close .year {
    color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .year {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 22%;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .info {
    width: 100%;
    width: 78%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding: 0 0 40px 35px;
    border-left: 4px solid #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .marker {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #aaa;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -14px;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline .timeline-item.active .info, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .info {
    color: #444;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.timeline .timeline-item.active .year, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .year {
    color: #0F8DC7;
}
.timeline .timeline-item .marker .dot {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid white;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline .timeline-item.active .marker .dot, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .marker .dot {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    background-color: #0F8DC7;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
img{
    transition: all 1s ease;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
img:hover{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
</style>
```

Hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me (in Chrome), when hovering the text only. -- http://jsfiddle.net/mssmL8qg/ Not really sure what the issue is, but have you tried referencing `.info:hover` instead?

Answer (score 0):

first of all,if u use HTML5, the center-tag is obsolete, use a div wrapper with fixed width and `margin:0px auto` to center the div. In ur case, its the `div.container`

```
div.container {
     width:1000px;
     margin:0px auto; /* instead of 0px choose ur own margin top and bottom */
}
```

to animate the img when hovering the timeline-item div, u have edit the last part `img:hover { [...] }` by changing its assignment to the img in the timeline-item:hover and add transition to it:

```
.timeline .timeline-item.active .info, .timeline .timeline-item:hover .info img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

works for me, tested in iron/chromium 38.